# Please teach me how to use ControlTemplate properly?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, controltemplate

Ok, I think I am pretty noob on using ControlTemplate lol...

All I want is to template my every UserControl so every UserControl will have Delete, Save, Cancel buttons.

So now I am writting some test......
Try to make a border around the everything...

In App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DeleteSaveCancelTemplate">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Border BorderThickness="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Black"> 
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then in UserControl:

```
<UserControl ...  Height="150" Width="300"  Template="{StaticResource DeleteSaveCancelTemplate}" >
```

But all I see is just ...black... what did I do wrong? I thought I should use ContentPresenter to shows the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I found the problem lol From [this page](http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Styles_and_Control_Templates%E2%80%94Content_Presenters)
The **ControlPresenter** doens't bind to Content by default...
I need to write

```
   <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" />
```

Unless you have specify the TargetType, then you it will bind by default.

Answer (score 0):

For most controls you use ContentPresenter. ItemsPresenter only applies to elements that extend ItemsControl.

Comment: I just realized that and I did try to use ContentPresenter, but it doens't work..